# Is there a >> monad operator in scalaz?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

Without Haskell's >> (monad replace?) operator, I can do this in scalaz:

```
val m3 = for {
  _ <- m1
  r <- m2
} yield r
```

Is there such an operator in Scalaz (6)? Once here, is there any auxillary operations like flatten/join, etc? Where are these defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `>>=|` with aliases `>|>` and `*|` defined in [scalaz/MA.scala](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/MA.scala).

Comment: Great! The last alias is a unicode sugar (mini nuclear warning sign maybe?). But for the normal ascii operator, why is it aliased? Should we rather use the >|> alias?